# Uploading gzipped csv file with pyspark?

Tags: pyspark, read.csv

I need to upload a csv.gz file using pyspark (in databricks) without changing it - could I read this in as if it were a regular csv file or would I have to do something different?

df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load(/FileStore/tables/skill2vec_50K_csv-1.gz)